# raspberry eth0 network interface name

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am working with several raspberry model 3 devices.

I have installed same `raspbian` version (latest) with NOOBS.

On some raspberry devices, I have an `eth0` network interface and on other raspberry I have an ethernet interface which name is `enXXXX`. I need on this raspberry to add `net.ifnames=0` in `/boot/cmdline.txt`.

My question is why the interface name is not the same? It seems to depend on hardware but this is the same model of raspberry.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at this answer on [raspberrypi.stackexchange.com](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43560/raspberry-pi-3-eth0-wrongfully-named-enx)?

Comment: yes this thread is not explaining why the behavior is different between 2 Rpi Model 3

Answer (score 0):

On those Raspbian that display `eth0` is probably running Raspbian Jessie (Debian 8), while those display 'enxxx` (en with the MAC address) is running on the latest Raspbian Stretch (Debian 9). To confirm it, run command line:

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

This [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) provide more background information.